# Fuzzy not functioning as expected (one term search, see example)

Tags: elasticsearch

Consider the following results from:

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/megacorp/employee/_search' -d 
'{ "query" : 
     {"match":  
        {"last_name": "Smith"}
     }
  }'
```

Result:

```
{
  "took": 3,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 2,
    "max_score": 0.30685282,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "megacorp",
        "_type": "employee",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 0.30685282,
        "_source": {
          "first_name": "John",
          "last_name": "Smith",
          "age": 25,
          "about": "I love to go rock climbing on the weekends.",
          "interests": [
            "sports",
            "music"
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "megacorp",
        "_type": "employee",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": 0.30685282,
        "_source": {
          "first_name": "Jane",
          "last_name": "Smith",
          "age": 25,
          "about": "I love to go rock climbing",
          "interests": [
            "sports",
            "music"
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Now when I execute the following query:

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/megacorp/employee/_search' -d 
'{ "query" : 
        {"fuzzy": 
             {"last_name": 
                  {"value":"Smitt", 
                   "fuzziness": 1
                  }
              }
         }
 }'
```

Returns NO results despite the Levenshtein distance of "Smith" and "Smitt" being 1.  The same thing results with a value of "Smit."  If I put in a `fuzziness` value of 2, I get results.  What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that the `last_name` field your are querying is an analyzed string. The indexed term will though be `smith` and not `Smith`.

> Returns NO results despite the Levenshtein distance of "Smith" and
>   "Smitt" being 1.

The `fuzzy` query don't analyze term, so actually, your Levenshtein distance is not 1 but 2 :

1. Smitt -> Smith
2. Smith -> smith

Try using this mapping, and your query with fuzziness = 1 will work :

```
PUT /megacorp/employee/_mapping
{
  "employee":{
    "properties":{
      "last_name":{
        "type":"string",
        "index":"not_analyzed"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Hope this helps